# Json stringify can't read with PHP

Tags: php, json, foreach

I am posting with jquery data variable, but PHP is can't read data variable

Javascript side:

```
var data = JSON.stringify(details);

$.ajax({
data: data,
type: 'POST',
url: '/dashboard/example.php',
});
```

PHP side:

```
$json=json_decode($_POST['data']);
foreach ($json as $value) {

...SQL update...

}
```

If i declarate data variable in PHP like this, it is worked, but post is not worked.

```
$string='[{"node":{"_DT_RowIndex":1},"oldData":"2","newData":"1","newPosition":0,"oldPosition":1},{"node":{"_DT_RowIndex":2},"oldData":"3","newData":"2","newPosition":1,"oldPosition":2},{"node":{"_DT_RowIndex":3},"oldData":"4","newData":"3","newPosition":2,"oldPosition":3},{"node":{"_DT_RowIndex":0},"oldData":"1","newData":"4","newPosition":3,"oldPosition":0}]';

$json=json_decode($_POST['data']);


foreach ($json as $value) {
...
}
```

Could you help me?

Comment: var dump `$_POST['data']` before decoding it and see what it is ?

Comment: Just check `$_POST['data']` by printing it out and work accordingly.  or try once `data: "'"+data+"'",`

Comment: I cannot echo in PHP file, so var_dump can't work

Comment: Then log (ie. using syslog), better if you could set up xdebug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) dosen't POST your custom data with key `data`, keys come from your data.

For example, if your data would be:

```
data: {foo: "Bar"}
```

Then `$_POST['foo']` would give you `Bar`.

If you want to get whole data with `$_POST['data']`, you have to set key first.

```
$.ajax({
  data: {
    data: data
  },
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/dashboard/example.php',
});
```

Now your `$_POST` will have `data` key. You can rename this key whatever you want.